# How can I use SQL Server to determine the number of minutes someone worked in every Hour of the day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Timeclock` table that has columns `[employeeid]`, `[clock in]`, and `[clock out]`.

I need to figure out how many minutes they've worked for each HOUR, for example:

```
Clockin:   11:30
Clockout:  12:37
```

I need to know you have:

```
11 hour:  30 min
12 hour:  37 min
```

Table structure:

```
|empid(int)|clockin(time(7))|clockout(time(7))|
|       103|        11:37:00|         12:37:00|
```

Here's my failed attempt:

```
select 
    hourlist.hour, employeelabor.empposid,
    case 
       when employeelabor.clockin < hourlist.hour 
            and employeelabor.clockout >= dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) 
         then '1:00:00.0'
       when employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour 
            and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) 
         then datediff(mi, employeelabor.clockout, employeelabor.clockin)
       when employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour 
            and employeelabor.clockout > dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) 
         then datediff(mi, 1, dateadd(mi, hourlist.hour, 1))
       when employeelabor.clockin < hourlist.hour 
            and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(HH,1,hourlist.hour) 
         then datediff(mi, hourlist.hour, employeelabor.clockout)
       else 0
     end minworked
from 
    hourlist
JOIN 
    dbo.EmployeeLabor ON (employeelabor.clockin >= hourlist.hour 
                          and employeelabor.clockin < dateadd(HH, 1, hourlist.hour) 
                          or (employeelabor.clockout >= hourlist.hour

                              and employeelabor.clockout < dateadd(HH, 1, hourlist.hour)
order by 
    hourlist.Hour
```

Comment: Could you at least post your table structure?

Comment: not sure why i got the -1, i don't know how i should be asking the question if I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe you should post some more sample data and expected results in a formatted way. Also, you should have tried something and post it. I'm not the one who gave you the downvote.

Comment: thanks for the response, i did attempt this, and was unsuccessful.  the feedback i got wasn't helpful, so i'm trying to simplify my request.

Comment: What about the situation where they clockIn at 10:30 and clockOut at 12:45? Should it display 10 hr : 30min, 11 hr 60min, 12 hour 45min?

Comment: Yes Greg, that's what I'd hope for.

Comment: I would edit your hourlist table to include a start_time and an end_time to make the join and case statements simpler. See solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For requirements like these, it helps to have a helper table. In this case, we will create a little `@hours` helper table, load it with 24 hours, and join this to the `Timeclock` table to return one record for each employee hour worked:

```
-- load test data
create table Timeclock(empid int,clockin time,clockout time)
insert into Timeclock values(103,'10:30','12:45')

-- load @hours helper table
declare @hours table (start_time time, end_time time)
declare @hour time = '00:00'
while (select count(*) from @hours) < 24
    begin
        insert into @hours values(@hour, dateadd(hour,1,@hour))
        set @hour = dateadd(hour,1,@hour)
    end

-- get minutes worked per hour per empid
select
    empid,
    datepart(hour,h.start_time) as [hour],
    datediff(minute,
        case
            when t.clockin > h.start_time
            then t.clockin
            else h.start_time
        end,
        case
            when isnull(t.clockout,getdate()) < h.end_time
            then isnull(t.clockout,getdate())
            else h.end_time
        end) as [minutes_worked]
from Timeclock t
    inner join @hours h
        on t.clockin < h.end_time
        and isnull(t.clockout,getdate()) >= h.start_time
```

Results:

```
empid       hour        minutes_worked
----------- ----------- --------------
103         10          30
103         11          60
103         12          45
```

SqlFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b92fe/1

Comment: I wish I could upvote the heck out of you!  This is awesome, elegant, and even more importantly ... TOTALLY solves my problem.  Thanks for showing me some great new usable stuff!

Comment: My pleasure. Really. I think this stuff is fun... 

Comment: any idea why i can't save that as a view?  it keeps saying incorrect syntax at declare

Comment: It's because of the variables. If you want it as a view, you need to create the @hours table as a permanent table.

Comment: This is working amazingly for me.  The only challenge I'm facing is that people who have not currently clocked out, do not show up until they've clocked out.  Ideally, they would show up with their current end_time=getdate()

Answer (score 0):

Can we try like that

```
declare @tb table
(
    empid int, 
    clockin time(2), 
    clockout time(2)
)

Insert into @tb (empid, clockin, clockout) VALUES (1, DATEADD(mi, 2, GETDATE()),  DATEADD(mi, 20, GETDATE()))
Insert into @tb (empid, clockin, clockout) VALUES (1, DATEADD(mi, -400, GETDATE()),  DATEADD(mi, 25, GETDATE()))
Insert into @tb (empid, clockin, clockout) VALUES (1, '11:37:00',  '12:37:00')

SELECT *, DATEDIFF(mi, clockin, clockout), CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(mi, clockin, clockout),  0), 114) FROM @tb
```